# How to choose correct drill bit size for screw and wallplug?

Tags: drill, masonry

I need to drill a hole into masonry wall.
I've never drilled a hole with a drill bit before and am confused about what size drill bit to use.
I have a screw, and I have a wall plug that will go into the hole.
So do I drill the size for the wall plug or the screw?
Even so, how do I measure to make sure I have the correct size?

Sounds novice I know, but I just don't want to make a mistake in the masonry.

Answer (score 2):

The wall plug may have a size molded into it, or the packaging will say. At any rate, the right size is usually the diameter at the widest point of the plug's taper (if present), not counting a flange. It should not take a lot of force to set the bare plug.

In the case of masonry (and most other materials) you can err on the small side and work larger until you get a good result.

Comment: Some plugs come with bit included.  Do not force bit to hard want  clean hole  round..., blow out dust should be snug tap in..